# Wordpress site won't load

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am getting this issue, anyone be able to help me?

> Warning:
>   require_once(/customers/4/7/0/jetpackprint.co.uk/httpd.www/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /customers/4/7/0/jetpackprint.co.uk/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/xstore/framework/thirdparty/tgm-plugin-activation/class-tgm-plugin-activation.php on line 2170
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/customers/4/7/0/jetpackprint.co.uk/httpd.www/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
>   /customers/4/7/0/jetpackprint.co.uk/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/xstore/framework/thirdparty/tgm-plugin-activation/class-tgm-plugin-activation.php
>   on line 2170

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the file `class-wp-list-tables.php` doesn't exists. Check by yourself if the file exists in your disk, otherwise this may be a permission error (the owner of the file is not the same that is running under php), but in most of the cases if was a permission error you had a "permission denied" error. Under certain circumstances you can fall in a "no such file or directory" for a permission error. Check if the file exists fist.

Comment: the file exists

Comment: Please check the owner of the file if is the same user that is running with php: you can check that going to the directory and typing `ls -la` will show you the list of the files, the owner and relative permissions. This works on *nix systems.